# Ternary coefficient of an integer in the range 1-1000 recursively in C

Tags: arrays, c, recursion, runtime-error, ternary

> I have to find the ternary coefficients for a given number.

For example, if the given number is 29, the desired output should be -1101.
Some more examples: 7 would give 1-11 and 10 would give 101.

I tried to solve the problem recursively using character arrays but I am new to C and hence, there is a runtime error that I cannot solve. The code is given here -

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *coefficient();

int main()
{
    int n;
    printf("Input a number between 1 and 1000: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    if(n<1 || n>1000){
        printf("Invalid Input. Please try again");
        scanf("%d",&n);
    }

    //Calculating the size of the char array
    int dummyN = n;
    int count = 1;
    while(dummyN>1){
        count++;
        dummyN/=3;
    }
    char c[count];

    printf("Coefficient sequence %s\n",coefficient(n,c));
    return 0;
}


char *coefficient(int n, char *c){
    if (n>1){
        int rem = n%3;
        n = n/3;
        char finrem;
        if(rem==2){
            rem = -1;
            n++;
        }
        else finrem = rem +'0';
        strcat(c, finrem);
        c=coefficient(n,c);
    }
    else if (n==1){
        char i = '1';
        strcat(c, i);
    }
    return c;
}
```

Comment: Watch very closely for uninitialized variables like `finrem` in your `coefficient()` function. It's only initialized on one branch. On the other it's just junk. Additionally `strcat` takes a `char*` C-string not a singular `char`. `finrem = rem +'0';` adds a literal *zero character* to the character, just trashing it. This is not the same as appending a NUL byte (ASCII character number `0`, not ASCII character zero `'0'`), though this could be some way of casting to ASCII numbers from a single digit?? In any case `strcat` still requires a character string, not a character.